# BigQuery DDL - rename a field?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a date partitoned table in BigQuery, and for the next release, we want to change the name of a field within the schema (to align with the model change for the input JSON events - its a level 1 in the schema hierarchy if level 0 is the 'top).

Current plan is to export / backup, do some migration work using the new schema, then save back to BQ, truncating the old table.  Should work but its a bit of a faf just to rename a single field.

Is there a better way to do this?  I couldnt see that BQ supports this in classic SQL DDL statement (standard SQL or legacy) - maybe I missed this?  This would of course be so much simpler!  Wont be the last time I need to do this either, be a great feature additon to standard SQL.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Big Query Table Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395612/update-big-query-table-schema)

Comment: Thanks Elliott (once again) - pretty much answers my question, only difference being I am trying to change nested data where the target field (a struct/record) to rename s at a level lower then the root - but thats just slightly different SQL then anyway.  Any plans for this type of maintenance DDL operation to be supported?

Comment: Not in the near future.